Button Text Insets in JavaFX
I feel like this is probably a problem with a simple fix, or I'm missing something obvious. I'm rusty (getting back in to some casual programming after years away) and I can't for the life of me figure it out.
I have a bunch of buttons that I want to keep smallish, but the text always truncates because of the insets between the border of the button and the text itself. How would I go about reducing those insets so the text is closer to the borders of the button? I'm using SceneBuilder and it doesn't have an option to change them, the only one I've found that might do it is greyed out.
The Button Brigade

I've been scouring the web for an answer but can't find one, since insets and buttons have a lot of relationships. Any help would be greatly appreciated!~
EDIT: So this will make a button that truncates the text even though that text would fit in the button if not for the insets within the button. I hope that clarifies things, sorry, pretty new to the site.~
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="274.0" layoutY="188.0" maxHeight="24.0" maxWidth="24.0" minHeight="24.0" minWidth="24.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="24.0" text="NW" />
    </children>
</Pane>


Save the fxml file.  Edit the question.  Provide the complete fxml file as text, formatted as code.  Then anybody can replicate your issue just by loading the fxml into scene builder or a JavaFX app.

Thanks for the tip, I have no idea what I'm really doing here~

The default application-wide user agent stylesheet (modena.css) gives buttons padding. You can override this by setting the padding property to something else (perhaps zero?).

To avoid truncating the text, you should avoid hard coding the size (preferred, minimum, and maximum) sizes. As noted in other comments, to reduce the space between the button content and the edge of the button, set the padding to values smaller than the default. Techniques for making the buttons the same size without hard-coding the sizes are shown in the official layout tutorial (those use Java, not FXML, but the same properties can be set in FXML and with SceneBuilder if needed).

This answer addresses what I think your main question is, which is how to adjust button padding.
I'm sure you may have additional questions as this answer is unlikely to answer all of your related queries, but, if so, it may be better to ask them as new questions.
Styling Button Padding using CSS
Button padding can be modified via CSS.
As noted by Slaw in comments:

The default application-wide user agent stylesheet (modena.css) gives buttons padding.
You can override this by setting the padding property to something else (perhaps zero?).

With an inline style
In code, you can write:
unpaddedButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px");

With an external stylesheet
But better to apply a CSS stylesheet:
.unpadded {
   -fx-padding: 0px; 
}   

Then you get in code:
unpaddedButton.getStyleClass().add("unpadded");

Applying a style to all buttons
Or, if you wanted to unpad all buttons in your app (unlikely), you could just have a stylesheet.
.button {
   -fx-padding: 0px; 
}

You can restrict this to some custom pane to style all buttons in the custom pane, by applying a style class of "custom-pane" (or any other name your want) to a layout pane containing all buttons you want styled.
.custom-pane > .button {
   -fx-padding: 0px; 
}

Using Scene Builder
To apply your own stylesheet and style classes to your FXML with scene builder, you can associate your custom CSS stylesheet with the FXML in scene builder and then apply the style. This process of using CSS style sheets from scene builder is documented in the Oracle Scene Builder guide (the Oracle documentation is outdated, but still relevant in this regard).
Setting padding using code
In addition to styling via CSS, you can use the JavaFX API in Java code to set the padding, this will override any CSS definitions.
unpaddedButton.setPadding(new Insets(0));

Example
This basic example removes padding from a button using an inline style.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ButtonPaddingApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Button paddedButton = new Button("Padded");
        Button unpaddedButton = new Button("Unpadded");
        unpaddedButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px");

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, paddedButton, unpaddedButton);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}

Related

How to make a javafx button with circle shape of 3xp diameter?

